# Pass actual color to value in input on js

Tags: javascript, jscolor

I need to pass color value to `<input>` dynamically so I could copy CSS then to clipboard. The color in question is that which changes automatically when you change bg color of the button. It's always black or white and it doesn't pass to `--placeholdtext` by itself. Now it's copied always white. I use http://jscolor.com/. The variable I think exists somewhere in jscolor.js file, couldn't find it and use.

### The code I have now:

```js
function copyToClipboard(element) {


  let currenttextColor = $(".jscolor").val();
  let currenttextStyle = $(element).text();

  let newtextStyle = currenttextStyle.replace('--placeholdtext', "#"+currenttextColor);

  document.getElementById('myField').value = currenttextColor;


    var $tempt = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($tempt);
  $tempt.val(newtextStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $tempt.remove();

   
 }
   
 function update(jscolor) {
      
       document.getElementById('button_cont').style.color = '#' + jscolor;


    }
```

```css
#button_cont {

color: --placeholdtext;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration: none;
 
padding: 10px;
/* border: 1px solid #ffffff; */
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jscolor/2.0.4/jscolor.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="button_cont" >Call to action</a>  

   
<button class="jscolor{valueElement:'valueInput', styleElement:'button_cont'}" >
    Pick a color
</button> 
 <input id="valueInput" value="ed3330">
<button onclick="copyToClipboard('style')">Copy button</button></div></div> 

<input type="text" id="myField" class="jscolor" onchange="update(this.jscolor);" style="display: none;" />
```

As you can see I use `document.getElementById('myField').value = currenttextColor;` to insert value with the color to the `<input>` below the code but I can't find the needed value variable with the black or white color.

Comment: No, there's the font color always changes to black or white but when I copy it to clipboard it's always white, I need to be able copy css with the right color

Comment: Ah, so you don’t want the (background) color the user actually picks, but the “complementary” black or white text color this chooses automatically for you, based on the BG color? Then read it from the link - `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('button_cont')).getPropertyValue('color')` (That will get you the `rgb` notation of the color - but if you _just_ need to know whether it is black or white, that should do.)

Comment: Thanks. I know it's wrong but when I put your code here `document.getElementById('myField').value = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('button_cont')).getPropertyValue('color');` I was able to copy the right rgb color but only once, second time it gave me this color rgb 255,255,255 though it wasn't the right one and then it always gave #FFFFFF; I don't know how to use the code I'm not a good coder

Comment: This way it works: `let currenttextColor = $(".jscolor").val();
  let currenttextStyle = $(element).text();

  let newtextStyle = currenttextStyle.replace('--placeholdtext', currenttextColor);


  var actualColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('button_cont')).getPropertyValue('color');

  document.getElementById('myField').value = actualColor;`  But now you need to press the Copy button twice to get the correct color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">



 function copyToClipboard(element) {


   var actualColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('button_cont')).getPropertyValue('color');

  document.getElementById('myField').value = actualColor;


  let currenttextColor = $(".jscolor").val();
  let currenttextStyle = $(element).text();

  let newtextStyle = currenttextStyle.replace('--placeholdtext', currenttextColor);



    var $tempt = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($tempt);
  $tempt.val(newtextStyle).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
 $tempt.remove();



 }  

</script>
```